# Is there a way to get multiple Image Extensions, in a link?

Tags: php

```
<img src="uploads/<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.jpg" class="img-circle" width="60" <b class="hidden-xs">
```

I am getting a User Image the Link is `uploads/admin.jpg` or also `uploads/?php echo $_SESSION['username'];?>.jpg`.

If they upload a .png how do I get it where it will choose the right extension for the Image so If it was a png instead of a JPG it would load the png image instead of the JPG? is there a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have options.

1) You can pre-process images uploaded to you (perhaps using [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php)) to force them to the one format you want before saving the file to your server.  This is probably the best solution.

2) You can accept the name of the uploaded file and store it in your database.  Thus, instead of:

`"uploads/<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>.jpg"`

you would use something like:

`"uploads/<?php echo $_SESSION['userimagefilename']; ?>"`

The problem with this solution is trust.  Users might not send you a filename that honestly represents the file contents.

3) Another solution is to use [exif_imagetype()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-imagetype.php).  This accepts an image, looks at the file contents, and tells you what the image type is (or isn't, in the case of nefarious users).  Combined with image_type_to_mime_type() you have the ability to stream the image as an inline HTML image and forget about what the suffix is.  This is especially handy if you store images in your DB rather than as files on disk, which is a problem when you try to store a lot of images.

4) A final solution is to if-then through a bunch of file_exists() statements.  However, you need to check at least three and should test a dozen file formats.  That's 1-12 disk hits per image.  It's an expensive solution and still doesn't protect you from someone uploading a file that isn't what it's pretending to be or uploading a file that isn't renderable as an image (e.g., .PDF, .DOC, .RTF, etc.).  It's my least favorite solution.

Comment: I'm probably going to make it where users are only able to upload .jpg files as their profile pictures.

Comment: A good, simple solution.  I'd recommend a quick test with exif_imagetype() to be sure it really is a JPG.  It's an inexpensive one-line test that will protect you from fools and felons alike.  Cheers!

Comment: I will! Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

```
if (file_exists('http://www.example.com/upload/'.$_SESSION['username'].'jpg')) 
{ 
    $src = $_SESSION['username'].'jpg';
}
else 
{ 
    $src = $_SESSION['username'].'png'; 
}

<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" class="img-circle" width="60" <b class="hidden-xs">
```